Possible to transfer face blend shapes that only affect the face and not the rest of the body?
I have two character meshes with identical number of vertices and identical vert order and identical shaped heads, BUT different shaped bodies. I'm wondering if it's possible to create face/expression blend shapes for one and copy them to the other in a way so that only the vertices of the face are changed and not the vertices of the whole body?
I tried this in another software but it didn't work, even though the blend shapes on the source character only moved facial vertices, when I applied them to the target character, the whole body was changed into the source character, not just the face expressions. I'm still pretty new to Blender.
Thank you very much for any information

In my example, male body has a shape key that elongates its head.
In object mode I select the male obj, I turn the shape key on, Shift select the female object, go to shape keys menu > Join as shape.
Now a shape key is created that deforms both head and body: select and activate this shape, go to edit menu, select all body vertices, go to vertex menu > Blend from shape, choose Basis and deactivate its "Add" preference, so that - in this Shape key - all body vertices get back to their Basis location.

Another method is to select all face's vertices and assign them to a vertex group, then use this vertex group to limit the action of the shape keys (Vertex group slot in the Shape keys tab).
